# Rewrite as asynchronous + Rewrite without arrow functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, arrow-functions

I'm learning code for Web Development and currently am working with JavaScript and Node.js -
I need to
(A.) Rewrite the code without using any arrow functions and
(B.) Rewrite the code using an async/await function.

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699")
.then(res => res.json())
.then((result) => {
      items= result.items;
      console.log(items);
    }),
  (error) => {
   console.log(error);
  }
```

Any and all help will be appreciated, I have tried to find help but I just can't make sense of it.

Comment: Beyond this, how would I write the code to display only the title and description of the book returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A)

```
fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699")
.then(function(res) { return res.json() })
.then(function(result) {
      const items= result.items;
      console.log(items);
    })
  .catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error);
  })
```

B)

```
async function getItems() {
  let results;
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699")
    results = await response.json()
  } catch (e) {
    return new Error('error......')
  }

  return results.items
}
const items = await getItems()
console.log(items)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your answer as A) and B) 
A) works perfectly, but B) holds issue as the identifier 'items' has already been declared. This is something I now understand I should have included in my original question's code. I'm not sure how to make it work with this information.

Comment: Hi @jeMcFadzean, this is not possible. "items" is only defined once in B. If your code has already defined a variable called "items", try to change the variable name. Change the "items" variable name to "resultItems" in B, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like so? Please let me know if this is what you want and if you need more information

```
async function getBooks() {
  try {
    const fetchResponse = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699");
    const result = fetchResponse.json();
    const books = result.items;
    console.log(books);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

// await getBooks();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This perfectly answers question B and is simple enough for me to follow. Do you have any good resources on arrow functions for question A?

Answer (score 0):

First, to read arrow functions, you have to understand there are two ways to return value in arrow functions:

```
const func = x => x * x;  // concise body syntax, implied "return"          
const func = (x, y) => { return x + y; };  // with block body, explicit "return" needed
```

Now, the following will go through the steps to convert code using a promise chain into code using `async/await`. By completing task B (replace promise chain with `async/await`), you will complete task A (code without arrow functions)

If a method returns a `Promise`, like `fetch` and `Body.json()` do, you can await its result:

```
const res = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699");
const result = await res.json();
items = result.items;
console.log(items);
```

To handle error without chaining `.catch`, you wrap the code with `try/catch` block:

```
try {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699"
  );
  const result = await res.json();
  items = result.items;
  console.log(items);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Lastly, `await` keyword can only be used inside an async function [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), that's why you have to wrap it into a function declared with `async`:

```
async function run() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699"
    );
    const result = await res.json();
    items = result.items;
    console.log(items);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
run();
```

You should also know that any function declared with `async` keyword also returns a Promise which you can await.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it step by step, this helped me to better understand. Unfortunately, A and B must be done separately. Perhaps you could point me to a resource where I can learn more about arrow functions?

Comment: Sure. This [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) may be helpful, especially the "Shorter functions" part. And @Pablo Darde's answer is pretty much what I would write.